# Not in sync, Achievements and Reputation

Tags: support, bug

I've been curious as to why these two are not in sync:

[image: Achievement and Reputation Tab Image]

I discovered this while browsing on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com). I noticed that my reputation changes without notice, so I checked the Reputation tab, and that's where I discovered it.